# Use WebGL texture as a Three.js Texture map

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I have a scene with plane which should use WebGL texture (created using `gl.createTexture()`) as a map for material. Basically, it doesn't matter how this texture will be used, I just need to find a way to pass it to the `ShaderMaterial` with certain uniform. WebGL texture updates every frame.

The texture is rendered in context of other canvas element and can be used in that context like this:

```
var imageLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "u_image");
gl.uniform1i(imageLocation, 0);
gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, targetTexture1);
```

I've already tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29325906/can-you-use-raw-webgl-textures-with-three-js?rq=1). But it seems like `THREE.Texture()` doesn't grab data from raw WebGL texture.

Comment: @Rabbid76 Of course I can use CanvasTexture to draw the texture from WebGL and than create a three.js texture using canvas data. Or use DataTexture and update data every frame. The first solution obviously will be slow, the second might be faster.

What I want to do is pass WebGL texture (not `THREE.Texture()`) to the `ShaderMaterial`. Is my question clear enough now?

Comment: my guess is that this is not possible. Why not use a three texture wrapper in the first place?

Answer (score 3):

If you dig through [the source](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js) this will work as of r103. Of course there's no guarantee it will work in the future but then [nothing in three is guaranteed to work in the future](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Migration-Guide).

First make a  `Texture` then call `forceTextureInitialization` to force Three.js to initialize the texture.

```
  const forceTextureInitialization = function() {
    const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial();
    const geometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry();
    const scene = new THREE.Scene();
    scene.add(new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material));
    const camera = new THREE.Camera();

    return function forceTextureInitialization(texture) {
      material.map = texture;
      renderer.render(scene, camera);
    };
  }();
```

Then replace that `Texture`'s WebGL texture with your own like this

```
const texProps = renderer.properties.get(someTexture);
texProps.__webglTexture = someGLTexture;
```

Example:

```js
'use strict';

/* global THREE */

function main() {
  const canvas = document.querySelector('#c');
  const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    canvas: canvas
  });
  
  const fov = 75;
  const aspect = 2; // the canvas default
  const near = 0.1;
  const far = 5;
  const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fov, aspect, near, far);
  camera.position.z = 2;

  const scene = new THREE.Scene();

  const boxWidth = 1;
  const boxHeight = 1;
  const boxDepth = 1;
  const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(boxWidth, boxHeight, boxDepth);
  
  const forceTextureInitialization = function() {
    const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial();
    const geometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry();
    const scene = new THREE.Scene();
    scene.add(new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material));
    const camera = new THREE.Camera();

    return function forceTextureInitialization(texture) {
      material.map = texture;
      renderer.render(scene, camera);
    };
  }();
  
  const cubes = []; // just an array we can use to rotate the cubes

  {
    const gl = renderer.getContext();
    const glTex = gl.createTexture();
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, glTex);
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, 2, 2, 0,
        gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, new Uint8Array([
          255, 0, 0, 255,
          0, 255, 0, 255,
          0, 0, 255, 255,
          255, 255, 0, 255,
        ]));
    gl.generateMipmap(gl.TEXTURE_2D);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
  
    const texture = new THREE.Texture();
    forceTextureInitialization(texture);
    const texProps = renderer.properties.get(texture);
    texProps.__webglTexture = glTex;
    
    const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
      map: texture,
    });
    const cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    scene.add(cube);
    cubes.push(cube); // add to our list of cubes to rotate
  }

  function render(time) {
    time *= 0.001;

    cubes.forEach((cube, ndx) => {
      const speed = .2 + ndx * .1;
      const rot = time * speed;
      cube.rotation.x = rot;
      cube.rotation.y = rot;
    });

    renderer.render(scene, camera);

    requestAnimationFrame(render);
  }

  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

main();
```

```html
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/103/three.min.js"></script>
```

Note of course instead of using your own texture you could grab the one the `Texture` is already using and then manipulate it with WebGL

Comment: Interesting, this is exposed as `.__webglTexture`, not all internals are  :(

Comment: The problem is that gl.createTexture() is created in other context: `bindTexture: object not from this context`. I dicided to use `gl.readPixels` and `THREE.DataTexture` but it takes 3-4ms to parse 1024x1024 texture.

Comment: There is no way to share textures across contexts period with WebGL. In three.js you can use a `CanvasTexture` which is probably faster than using `gl.readPixels`. You could also consider using [virtual webgl contexts](https://github.com/greggman/virtual-webgl)

Comment: This still works as of r136