# Can a webgl shader run within three.js?

Tags: three.js, webgl

I want to process a webgl texture within three.js, to do so, i wrote a webgl shader.

If I run the pen with "use_three" set to false, it's all good but if i set it to true i get a black result. any ideas ?

```
pen : https://codepen.io/joserpagil/pen/XWyGOPY?editors=0010
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following template based on `ShaderMaterial` for your code:

```js
let camera, scene, renderer;

init();
animate();

function init() {

  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(40, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.01, 10);
  camera.position.set(0, 0, 1);

  scene = new THREE.Scene();

  const geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry();

  const material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({

    vertexShader: document.getElementById('vertexShader').textContent,
    fragmentShader: document.getElementById('fragmentShader').textContent

  });

  const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
  scene.add(mesh);

  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

}

function animate() {

  requestAnimationFrame(animate);

  renderer.render(scene, camera);

}
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.149.0/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script id="vertexShader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">

            void main() {

                gl_Position = vec4( position, 1.0 );

            }

</script>

<script id="fragmentShader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">

            void main() {

                gl_FragColor = vec4 ( 1., .45, .7, 1. );

            }

</script>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply but what i'm looking for is to run a raw webgl shader in three.js so that i can process a webgl texture

Comment: Oh I see. Unfortunately, this kind of low-level setup is not supported without modifying the library. I suggest you try to figure out a three.js only solution for your use case.

Comment: in fact that's what i did, using this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/55084367/17519793

Comment: I'm not sure this hack works with the latest version. It's not recommended in any event since you potentially bypass internal optimizations and there is no guarantee that this works in future releases.

Comment: well it's working on 156dev, i'm aware it's a hack. could it be added properly to the cannon ?